# How to get the Django model with maximum field value?

Tags: python, django, orm

I have a Django class that looks like this:

```
class MyModel(models.Model):
    my_integer = models.IntegerField(default=-1)
    created_ts = models.DateTimeField(default=datetime.utcnow, editable=False)
```

How can I get the instance of the model (not just the value of the field) that has the latest `created_ts` for a given value of `my_integer`? I thought the line below using **annotate** would work, However that retuned to me all 3 instances of MyModel that had `my_integer==77` instead of the single value I was expecting. And weirdly, each of these 3 instances has `last_created` set to its own `created_ts` instead of the max of all matching instances.

```
>>> len(MyModel.objects.filter(my_integer=77))
3

>>> from django.db.models import Max, F
>>> x = MyModel.objects.filter(my_integer=77).annotate(last_created=Max('created_ts')).filter(created_ts=F('last_created'))
>>> len(x)
3

>>> print x[0].my_integer, x[0].created_ts, x[0].last_created
77 2015-09-07 07:46:27.343869 2015-09-07 07:46:27.343869

>>> print x[1].my_integer, x[1].created_ts, x[1].last_created
77 2015-09-12 07:46:27.343869 2015-09-12 07:46:27.343869

>>> print x[2].my_integer, x[2].created_ts, x[2].last_created
77 2015-09-13 07:46:27.343869 2015-09-13 07:46:27.343869
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`.latest()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.latest) on the queryset. So you can get the object as

```
obj = MyModel.objects.filter(my_integer=77).latest('created_ts')
```

You can also use [`.order_by()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/models/querysets/#order-by) and `.first()`

```
obj = obj = MyModel.objects.filter(my_integer=77).order_by('-created_ts').first()
```

Comment: Wow. This was so helpful. Thank you for telling me about `.latest()`!